# sizeThatFits: is returning different Values iOS 5 and iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uilabel

I am calling `sizeThatFits:` on a UILabel in a ImageView subclass and I located the error to be `sizeThatFits:`.  On iOS 5 I am getting 3 lines and on iOS 6 1 line.

```
CGSize labelSize = [mTitleLabel sizeThatFits: CGSizeMake(self.bounds.size.width, 30)];
CGFloat lines = ceil(labelSize.width/self.frame.size.width);
```

I tried to do the calculation myself by calling the following method, but I am getting 7 instead of 3 on both versions.

```
float lines = mTitleLabel.frame.size.height/mTitleLabel.font.lineHeight;
lines = ceilf(lines);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that sizeThatFits: is broken in iOS5, ignoring the number of lines.

NSString * title = ...;
CGSize sizeToFit = [title sizeWithFont:label.font constrainedToSize:label.frame.size lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];